# Applications of Kazamaki Conditions

Tags: stochastic-calculus, mathematical-finance

I'm interested in applications of this theorem by Sekiguchi Kazamaki:

*"Continuous Exponential Martingales and BMO" - Theorem 1.12:*
*Let $M$ be a continuous local martingale and $Z(M):= \exp(M-\frac{1}{2} [M])$ the stochastic exponential of $M$ and let $\phi$ be a lower function. If

$\sup_{T}  E [ \exp ( \alpha M_T + (\frac{1}{2} - \alpha) [M]_T - |1-\alpha| \phi([M]_T))] < \infty$

for a $\alpha \not = 1$, then $(Z_t)_{t \in [0,\infty]}$ is a uniformly integrable martingale.*

I'm searching for application in mathematical finance. Of course, this theorem will be used to apply known Girsanov's theorem for change of measure. But I can't find cases in literature where we need $Z$ to be a uniformly martingale on whole timeline $[0,\infty]$, but only on a bounded timeline $[0,T]$. Do you know some books or papers? Thank you very much.